# scrapy - data from the following pages

Tags: scrapy

I have a problem.
How to do to download data after moving to the next pages?
It only downloads from the first page.
I paste, my code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class PronobelSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pronobel'
    allowed_domains = ['pronobel.pl']
    start_urls = ['http://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy/']

    def parse(self, response):

        jobs = response.xpath('//*[@class="offer offer-immediate"]')
        for job in jobs:
            title = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-title"]/text()').extract_first()
            start_date = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-attr offer-departure"]/text()').extract_first()
            place = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-attr offer-localization"]/text()').extract_first()
            language = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-attr offer-salary"]/text()').extract()[1]

            print title
            print start_date
            print place
            print language

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="page-nav nav-next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url)
```

I only get data from the first page

Comment: Are you saying your spider is not going to the next pages? Also, you need to `yield` your data as well, not print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not about crawling the next page, your problem is on your selector.
First of all, when selecting an element by class, it's [recommended to use css](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css).
What is happening is there are no elements with the class `offer-immediate` on other pages.

I made a few changes on your code, see bellow:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class PronobelSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pronobel'
    allowed_domains = ['pronobel.pl']
    start_urls = ['http://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy/']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.css('div.offers-list div.offer')
        for job in jobs:
            title = job.css('a.offer-title::text').extract_first()
            start_date = job.css('div.offer-attr.offer-departure::text').extract_first()
            place = job.css('div.offer-attr.offer-localization::text').extract_first()
            language = job.css('div.offer-attr.offer-salary::text').extract()[1]
            yield {'title': title,
                    'start_date': start_date,
                    'place': place,
                    'language': language,
                    'url': response.url}

        next_page_url = response.css('li.page-nav.nav-next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class PronobelSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pronobel'
    allowed_domains = ['pronobel.pl']
    start_urls = ['http://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy']

    def parse(self, response):

        jobs = response.xpath('//*[@class="offer offer-immediate"]')
        for job in jobs:
            title = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-title"]/text()').extract_first()
            start_date = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-attr offer-departure"]/text()').extract_first()
            place = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-attr offer-localization"]/text()').extract_first()
            language = job.xpath('.//*[@class="offer-attr offer-salary"]/text()').extract()[1]

            yield {'place' : place}

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="page-nav nav-next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)  
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url)
```

Reply:

```
2019-03-20 17:58:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-03-20 17:58:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-03-20 17:58:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6025
2019-03-20 17:58:28 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy> from <GET http://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy>
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy> (referer: None)
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy>
{'place': u'Ratingen'}
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy>
{'place': u'Burg Stargard'}
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy>
{'place': u'Fahrenzhausen'}
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy>
{'place': u'Meerbusch'}
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy>
{'place': u'Geislingen an der Steige T\xfcrkheim/Deutschland'}
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy?page_nr=2> (referer: https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy)
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy?page_nr=3> (referer: https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy?page_nr=2)
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://pronobel.pl/praca-opieka-niemcy?page_nr=3> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2019-03-20 17:58:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```